# Integral of functions within functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, integral-equations

I define the function Rho, use it in an integration command, store that result as a new function M, then write functions P and Rho1 in terms of M and Rho, and finally integrate Rho1 and store that as the new function M1. However, I do not get any output at all. I would like to see the results for  M and M1 when those integrals are performed. Thanks, and sorry if my formatting is bad, I'm just getting used to things.

```
A = 21.38
B = 19.81
a = 3.01
b = 3.82
Rho[r_] := rho0*(r^2)*rho0*((A/((a^2) + (r0^2)/(r^2))) - (B/((b^2) + (r0^2)/(r^2))))

M[r_] := Integrate[4*pi*Rho[r], r]

P[r_] := ((m/(2*pi*k*T))^(3/2))*(8*pi*G/r)*M[r]*Exp[(-m*M[r]*G)/(k*T*r)]

Rho1[r_] := P[r]*Rho[r]*4*pi*(r^2)

M1[r_] := Integrate[Rho1[r], r]
M[r]
M1[r]
```

Comment: Watch out - in both integrals you've got `r` as the variable you're integrating over, but you've also got `r_` as an argument. If you called `M[f, 1]` for instance, the integral would end up being `Evaluate[Integrate[4*pi*f[1], {1, 0, 1}]]` which makes no sense. Also the `Evaluate`'s seem pointless and are actually holding up your definition of the functions. Once those two things are fixed, you need to call the M1 function in the next line.

Comment: Ok, I've cleaned it up a little. Now it solves the first integral, but the second one it just prints out still in integral form

Comment: The symbolic integral is probably just too hard. Also did  you mean pi as a symbol or Pi (the constant) ? If all these other symbols (k,G,r0,T ... etc) had numeric values, then you could `NIntegrate` it instead.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: @flinty Thank you for your help. Agh.. jeez ok I guess it's just not solvable unless I give numerical bounds of integration. The symbols k, G, T, etc. are just constants so I guess I'll define them and try NIntegrate